# Changing one material in MeshRenderer.materials and don't instantiate all the materials

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to change and therefore instantiate only one material in the materials array. Currently, if I access `MeshRenderer.materials`, unity returns an array of instantiated materials.

> This function automatically instantiates the materials and makes them unique to this renderer.
> ([Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html))

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

**More info on what I'm trying to do:**

I have an object with 10 material slots that is used frequently in the scene.

The first 5 slots use Material-A which is using GPU Instancing with colour as the instancing property, And the second 5 slots use Material-B which is not using GPU Instancing and its texture is being assigned at runtime.

Therefore when a texture is assigned to the second 5 slots at runtime, It then defeats the purpose of GPU Instancing the first 5 slots.

Is there a way other than GPU Instance Material-B using Texture2DArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing materials containing `"Material-A"` in their name with `Resources.Load("Material-A") as Material` to reference the original Material-A whenever I change Material-B's texture.

```
var mats = meshRenderer.materials;
mats[materialIndex].mainTexture = texture;
for (var i = 0; i < mats.Length; i++)
    if (mats[i].name == "Material-A (Instance)")
        mats[i] = Resources.Load("Material-A") as Material;
meshRenderer.materials = mats;
```

I would appreciate it if you have a better way...

Comment: Doesn't this still call `meshRenderer.materials` and thereby already underly the original problem of instantiating all Materials?

Comment: @derHugo The first line gets the materials therefore they are instantiated, then I replace the instantiated materials with the original material, and finally set them back into the materials in which the setter doesn't instantiate them again.

Comment: Either way it does instantiate them only **once** per renderer anyway though ;) So as said since you access `materials` you already instantiate them

Comment: @derHugo Yes in fact they are instantiated once, but the problem was that they would become different materials and therefore break batching. With the code above I could replace the instantiated materials with the original one and therefore prevent breaking the batch caused by different materials.

Comment: Ah I see .. now I start to get what the actual question was :'D .. instead of the `Resources` I think you could also (and rather) pre-cache the original materials beforehand using the `sharedMaterials` before the first material instancing (so e.g. in `Awake`)

Comment: I'm actually using this piece of code for the material: `private static Material _colorMaterial;` `public static Material ColorMaterial => _colorMaterial ? _colorMaterial : _colorMaterial = Resources.Load("ColorMaterial") as Material;` but replaced it to simplify my answer. But getting them from `sharedMaterials` is actually a good idea, Thanks!